# Double integral region enclosed by $D$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The integral I have is $$\iint _Dx^3y\:\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,$$ where $D:\:y=x^2,\:y=-x^2,\:x=1$.

I am not sure if I did the boundary right, is it correct this way? $$\int _0^1\left(\int _{-x^2}^{x^2}\:x^3y\,\mathrm{d}x\:\right)\mathrm{d}y$$

I just wanna figure out the boundary, no need to evaluate the integral.
[image]

Comment: Yes it is correct bounds. You can draw and see it.

Comment: Make sure you put $dy\,dx$ instead of $dx\,dy$, otherwise you're integrating using horizontal slices instead of vertical slices.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the desmos, I have a hard time figuring out these things honestly, also thanks for pointing out the dydx.

Comment: Is this a textbook exercise on formulating the integral? The answer is trivially zero, and you wouldn't need to perform the integral to find that out.

Comment: No, it was one of many integrals I had to evaluate from a paper sent to us by the teacher, I am not sure where it is from, it's just exercises to better understand if we wanted to do them.

Comment: Is there a way I can mark the question as answered? Sorry I am still fairly new and not sure yet about these things...